# Why does the "TypeError: argument fn must be a function" error occur when running an Angular project?

Tags: angular

I just started learning angular. I'm creating an empty Angular project. When I try to run the project I get an error like the following. This may be the cause.

```
ng new intro
ng serve --open
```

> argument fn must be a function TypeError: argument fn must be a
>   function
>       at Function.wrapfunction [as function] (C:\kurs\angularProjects\intro\node_modules\depd\index.js:399:11)
>       at populateConstructorExports (C:\kurs\angularProjects\intro\node_modules\http-errors\index.js:264:45)
>       at Object. (C:\kurs\angularProjects\intro\node_modules\http-errors\index.js:30:1)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:683:19)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
>       at Object. (C:\kurs\angularProjects\intro\node_modules\send\index.js:15:19)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:683:19)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)

Comment: you typed this whole line into a terminal at once? `ng new intro` will generate a new project once that is done, then you run it with `ng serve --open`

Comment: I am generate a new project with "ng new intro". Then I try to run it with "ng serve --open".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved for me. This error occurred in the 12.6.0 Current version of node.js. I changed the version of node.js. I installed LTS version 10.16.0 and no error occurred

Answer (score 3):

This problem occurs in Turkish workstations with newer versions of node.js.

You should change the system language or downgrade your node.js version.

See: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7315

In my Windows 10 Home Premium Single Language license workstation, changing the language with an lp.cab file didn't solve problem.

I formatted and installed clean Windows Home Premium English.

Problem disappeared!

Answer (score 1):

Open the file node_modules\depd\index.js and change the function below.

```
function wrapfunction (fn, message) {
if (fn == undefined) return; // Add this line to solve the problem
if (typeof fn !== 'function') {
throw new TypeError('argument fn must be a function ' + fn)
}
```

Comment: Editing `node_modules` is a bad idea, this fix will get lost when you do a `npm install`. What you should do instead if you have found a bug is to fork the npm module, fix the issue, and create a pull request so the maintainers can merge it and publish a new version of the package.